# How can I set bordercolor with using ng-class in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, html, css, angularjs

I have a list of items and I'm populating it using radio buttons. Now, I want to change border color of the item to red using `ng-class` when the associated radio button is clicked. This part is actually working. However, when I click on another item's radio button, the previous clicked item border is not unselected.

```css
.selected{
    border-color:red;
}
.unselected{
    border-color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="clients" value="even" ng-click="selectClient(x)" ng-model="x.isSelected">

<span class="split bqm-focus" ng-class="{selected:x.isSelected,unselected:!x.isSelected}">
    <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{x.LogoSmall}} "  />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 ng-class="{x.isSelected? 'selected': 'unselected'}"
```

Or in your case

```
 ng-class="{ 'selected': x.isSelected, 'unselected': !x.isSelected  }"
```

Comment: Show the `selectClient` method, does x.isSelected even gets updated?

Comment: Make sure you have `border-width` and `border-style` set as well as `border-color`.